# How to crop bitmap in UWP app?

Tags: c#, pdf, bitmap, uwp, syncfusion

There are many similar questions, but none of them seem to answer my problem.

I am working on an UWP app (with Syncfusion), which can generate some PDF.
To this PDF, I need to get some Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics.PdfBitmap, but before that, I need to crop it a little bit.

This is what i am doing, I get my diagram and transform it into PdfBitmap:

```
 var diagramBitmap = new PdfBitmap(diagram);
```

Then i need to draw it into PDF by:

```
 document.Pages[0].Graphics.DrawImage(diagramBitmap, x, y, width, height);
```

Problem is, none of the solutions i found worked easily in UWP to crop that PdfBitmap before drawing it.
I solved that problem without cropping a diagram, it's working, but to crop it is much more better and nicer solution.

Thanks for your help or an advice!

Answer (score 8):

This code creates a new cropped SoftwareBitmap from an existing SoftwareBitmap. Useful if the image already is in memory.

```
    async public static Task<SoftwareBitmap> GetCroppedBitmapAsync(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap, 
            uint startPointX, uint startPointY, uint width, uint height)
    {            
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);

            encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);

            encoder.BitmapTransform.Bounds = new BitmapBounds()
            {
                X = startPointX,
                Y = startPointY,
                Height = height,
                Width = width
            };

            await encoder.FlushAsync();

            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

            return await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat, softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works good. But to be on the safe side, I would check the new Bounds if they are valid, or surround the cropping with a try catch

Answer (score -1):

> Problem is, none of the solutions i found worked easily in UWP to crop that PdfBitmap before drawing it. I solved that problem without cropping a diagram, it's working, but to crop it is much more better and nicer solution.

You can crop it before the `PdfBitmap` creation.There is a good Sample project for cropping images in UWP. Please refer to [UWP-ImageCropper](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-ImageCropper-). You can modify the core function like below to let it meet your requirement:

```
/// <param name="originalImgFile">Image File that you want to crop</param>
/// <param name="startPoint">From which point you want to crop</param>
/// <param name="corpSize">The crop size of the image</param>
/// <param name="scale">The scale of cropped image</param>
async public static Task<Stream> GetCroppedBitmapAsync(StorageFile originalImgFile, System.Drawing.Point startPoint, System.Drawing.Size corpSize, double scale)
{
    if (double.IsNaN(scale) || double.IsInfinity(scale))
    {
        scale = 1;
    }


    // Convert start point and size to integer. 
    uint startPointX = (uint)Math.Floor(startPoint.X * scale);
    uint startPointY = (uint)Math.Floor(startPoint.Y * scale);
    uint height = (uint)Math.Floor(corpSize.Height * scale);
    uint width = (uint)Math.Floor(corpSize.Width * scale);


    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await originalImgFile.OpenReadAsync())
    {


        // Create a decoder from the stream. With the decoder, we can get  
        // the properties of the image. 
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);

        // The scaledSize of original image. 
        uint scaledWidth = (uint)Math.Floor(decoder.PixelWidth * scale);
        uint scaledHeight = (uint)Math.Floor(decoder.PixelHeight * scale);



        // Refine the start point and the size.  
        if (startPointX + width > scaledWidth)
        {
            startPointX = scaledWidth - width;
        }

        if (startPointY + height > scaledHeight)
        {
            startPointY = scaledHeight - height;
        }


        // Create cropping BitmapTransform and define the bounds. 
        BitmapTransform transform = new BitmapTransform();
        BitmapBounds bounds = new BitmapBounds();
        bounds.X = startPointX;
        bounds.Y = startPointY;
        bounds.Height = height;
        bounds.Width = width;
        transform.Bounds = bounds;


        transform.ScaledWidth = 100;
        transform.ScaledHeight = 100;

        // Get the cropped pixels within the bounds of transform. 
        PixelDataProvider pix = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
            transform,
            ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
            ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
        byte[] pixels = pix.DetachPixelData();


        // Stream the bytes into a WriteableBitmap 
        WriteableBitmap cropBmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);
        Stream pixStream = cropBmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        pixStream.Write(pixels, 0, (int)(width * height * 4));


        return pixStream;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it for your `PdfBitmap` creation:

```
var imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image03.jpg"));
Stream  bitmap = await GetCroppedBitmapAsync(imageFile, new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100), new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100), 1);
PdfBitmap image = new PdfBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: What if the bitmap you want to crop is already in memory (as a SoftwareBitmap, for instance)?